# Swipe images through appium-android and to zoom

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I started learning appium a few days back. Below is my scenario :

1. open the flipkart
2. Click on main menu
3. scroll till mobiles
4. click on mobiles
5. click on specific mobile
6. click on mobile image and swipe between images
7. zoom the image.

Below is the code I implemented for above scenario :

```
driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("home_menu_className"))).click();
    System.out.println("clicked on home menu");
    driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("home_menu_className"))).click();
    WebElement mobile = driver.scrollTo("Mobiles");
    System.out.println("scroll till Mobiles in home slider menu");
    mobile.click();
    driver.scrollTo("Top Offers!!").click();
    driver.scrollTo("Honor 4x").click();
    delay(4000);
    WebElement honor = driver.findElementById("com.flipkart.android:id/product_list_product_item_image");
    taction.tap(honor);
    driver.swipe(495,484, 52, 484, 12000);
    delay(12000);
    driver.zoom(164, 644);
    delay(8000);
```

When I run above code,  displays swipe action with x-axis and y-axis on the same page from right to left.And it doesn't swipe between images and doesn't zoom.

Please can anyone tell me the exact way of doing it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try TouchAction class to perform the swiping function.

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(x,y).moveTo(x, y).release();
action.perform();
```

Comment: I have even used TouchAction class but getting error as invalid coordinates something like this.Using the  coordinates mentioned in the above code.

Comment: from where did u get these coordinates?

Comment: By enabling "show pointer location" in developer options . And whenever am using swipe or scroll methods , getting error as org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)